# Laravel4 Session handling issue?

Tags: laravel-4

I want to use Laravel Database Session. I have changed

'driver' => 'database',

in session.php.

When I try to access application i.e during landing page or before login 
I am getting this error

**null value in column "data" violates not-null constraint DETAIL**

But if this error comes after login, then it is fine. Because that is when session is created. I did not understand why it is coming during application load.

Please let me know what is the issue or Please let me know the tutorial link for session handling in Laravel4

Thanks all

Comment: What have you done?  Have you run the `migrations` required for the Session package?

Comment: No i have created sessions table directly in db

Answer (score 0):

The "data" value you reference doesn't exist in the implementation of the Laravel session handler.  The fields are `id`, `payload` and `last_activity`.

If you're trying to use Laravel's session handler via database, you're going to need to run the Laravel migrations.

Go to your command line and run artisan.  `php artisan session:table` will automatically create the Laravel session migrations.

Then run `composer dump-autoload` or `composer.phar dump-autoload` (depending on your implementation).

Next, `php artisan migrate` and your Laravel session table will be created!  You'll now be able to use laravel's built-in session handler.

Documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/session#database-sessions

Comment: ok, how can I add new column into sessions table. what if I want store extra data in session table. will it work if I add it in migration table

Comment: You could do that, yes.  Before running `php artisan migrate` you'll need to go in to the `app/database/migrations` folder and add your columns there.  What are you interested in storing?

Comment: user related data, can you come on chat

Comment: Sure.  Send a link my way.